# Syntax error: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module line: 1 file: Code.gs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I wanted to create a script, which would send data from the google form to the discord webhook in google apps script. But I receive the error in the first line:

```
import { client as _client } from 'discord.js';
const client = new _client();
```

Here is the error:

```
Syntax error: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module line: 1 file: Code.gs
```

Comment: your error stems from a flawed import statement. It looks like you are using the common.js type which uses `require` instead of `import`. You can read up on it [here](https://code-trotter.com/web/understand-the-different-javascript-modules-formats/)

Comment: im using google apps script, if i will use require, ill receive ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58211880/1595451

Comment: It doesn't help me. I don't know where I should type "type": "module".

Comment: ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47639463/send-message-to-discord-via-google-apps-script

Comment: my current code is https://pastebin.com/4NXgAkgd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

discord.js depends on Node.js. It cannot run on Google Apps Script.

If you want to contact a discord webhook, then do so directly using the `UrlFetchApp` API as per the [External APIs guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external).

Answer (score 0):

> Currently, Google Apps Script does not support ES modules. Hence the
> typical export/import pattern cannot be used and will fail.
>
> One way of handling this is to use rollup.js to bundle your project
> into one single JavaScript file.
>
> The trick here is to make sure not to export any functions in your
> entry point code, e.g. index.ts, and to prevent any generation of
> export statement in the final bundle (see the custom rollup plugin in
> the rollup.config.js below).

See code: https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/esmodules.md

See also: [The ULTIMATE Guide to NPM Modules in Google Apps Script](https://medium.com/geekculture/the-ultimate-guide-to-npm-modules-in-google-apps-script-a84545c3f57c)

Or even: [Using npm modules inside of Apps Script](https://jeffy.info/2021/07/12/npm-from-apps-script.html)

Comment: This won't help. discord.js depends on Node.js APIs that rollup cannot bundle.