# How to edit Discord webhook on Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, discord

All I know is how to [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47639463/send-message-to-discord-via-google-apps-script?newreg=41568e77ba494fd4bdfd015697d83181) but not edit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the script editor on your google sheet
2. Paste the contents of the main.gs file into the script editor
3. Open Discord, go to 'Server Settings' > 'Integrations' > 'Webhooks'
4. Create a 'New Webhook' & fill in all the fields necessary.
5. Copy the webhook link & paste this link into the "WEBHOOKURL".
6. In the google sheet script editor, using the left-hand side menu, navigate to 'Triggers' and add a new trigger.

For more detailed steps you can visit https://github.com/Kelo/Google-Sheets-to-Discord